# cy.wrap() timed out waiting 4000ms to complete in mailosaur

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm running into a CypressError when calling cy.mailosaurGetMessage: cy.wrap() timed out waiting 4000ms to complete.

Please find the attached image for error.
[image]

Please find the code snippet below:`

```
describe('Password reset', () => {
    const serverId = 'u7ob3rfc1'; 
    const testEmail = 'uma@u7ob3rfc1.mailosaur.net'

    it('Gets a link blocked email', () => {
        console.log("inside")
        cy.mailosaurGetMessage(serverId, {
            sentTo: testEmail,
        }).then(email => {
            receivedAfter: new Date('2020-03-06T00:00:00Z')
            console.log(email.subject)
            expect(email.subject).to.equal('Click Blocked');
        })
    })
})
```

`

Comment: Please post the entire code that is causing the error.

Comment: Please format this and update this in the main question.

Comment: @AlapanDas..Please find the updated question

Comment: Hey Amu, you are using version 1.08 (or earlier) of mailosaur but the latest is v2.12. There may be some bug fixes you are missing out on.

Comment: Also, somewhere you have set timeout as a string `timeout: '1000'` but it should be a number `timeout: 1000`. Not sure if that causes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the top of the screenshot, there's a `timeout: 100010000` - which is really weird for a timeout number

See this bit of code from the mailosaur library, in **mailosaurCommands.js**

```js
cy.wrap(new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fn(resolve, reject)();
}), {
  log: false,
  timeout: options.timeout + 10000
});
```

The timeout the user gives is being increased by 10 seconds, except that for your test setup `options.timeout` is a string instead of a number giving that super large and weird timeout in the screen shot above.

So somewhere you have used

```
timeout: '1000'
```

but instead you should use

```
timeout: 1000
```

**Why is this a problem?**

The `cy.wrap()` above contains a Promise, which must either resolve or reject before Cypress continues. But it neither resolves or rejects which is why you get

> **cy.wrap() timed out waiting 4000ms to complete**.

I think this might also be due to the incorrect timeout, it is hard to tell without debugging it, but at least one place where the Promise resolves is affected by it.